# Nested Dictionary Key changing from Int to Str

Tags: python

I am looking to save a dictionary as a json file. Prior to implementing a way to save user input the original key in my nested dictionary was always an int but now that it is being saved into a json file it has been converted to a string. Is there any way to have the nested dictionary key save as an int rather than as a string? Below is what is getting stored in my json file:

```
{"1": {"Recipe Name": "Sourdough bread", "Category": "Rustic Breads", "Preptime": "18 hours", "Cooktime": "1 hour", "Ingredients": "Flour, Water, Starter", "Instructions": "Mix and Bake"}}
```

Edit: It was brought to my attention that json files always save them as string values. Within the logic of my code I was allowing users to enter the number ( in this instance the number 1 ) to select the recipe they wanted to view, edit or remove and I was using isinstance ( see example below ) to verify the user was entering an in int to ensure they could not enter a string.

```
if int(edit_selection) == isinstance(int(edit_selection), int):
```

What can I do to validate that the user input corresponds to that number if its converted into a string, would I need to create a list of numbers ( that are strings) from lets say 1 to 500 that it would check against?

Comment: Key values are always strings in JSON... (well... if you want to be compliant to the specification anyway...)

Comment: on disk raw JSON isn't really meant as a storage format... it's meant to be used for a general data transport format - can you not use sqlite or something?

Comment: Also... just a side note: `if int(edit_selection) == isinstance(int(edit_selection), int)` - if it's not something convertible on the left hand side - it's going to raise an exception and the right hand side is just misleading anyway.

Comment: (eg... the left is going to return an actual `int`... the right hand side is going to return a `bool`... so you end up comparing if 500 is equal to 0 or 1)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to achieve this :

```
my_list = {"1": {"Recipe Name": "Sourdough bread", "Category": "Rustic Breads", "Preptime": "18 hours", "Cooktime": "1 hour", "Ingredients": "Flour, Water, Starter", "Instructions": "Mix and Bake"}}
output_dict = {}
for key, value in my_list.items():
    output_dict[int(key)] = value

print(output_dict)
```

The output is : `{1: {'Recipe Name': 'Sourdough bread', 'Category': 'Rustic Breads', 'Preptime': '18 hours', 'Cooktime': '1 hour', 'Ingredients': 'Flour, Water, Starter', 'Instructions': 'Mix and Bake'}}`